# Update varios registros de uma vez laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sql-update

Olá,
Tenho uma tabela com os seguintes campos:`KEY, VALUE , ALIAS, CLIENT_ID`.
Em determinado processo do sistema eu preciso fazer o update do Key e o Value.

Para fazer o update em apensa um registro eu não tenho problemas, o problema é que quando eu preciso alterar duas KEYS e dois VALUES de um client ID eu estou usando a função update do laravel/repositories, então o codigo ficou assim:

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
 {
    $this->client->update($request->all(), $id);
 }
```

O problema é que com esse metodo se eu tiver 2 values e 2 keys, ele sobrepõe a primeira então o que eu recebo é apenas

```
request = [ key => 'segundo valor do form', value => 'segundo valor do form'];
```

Eu preciso que venham as 2 keys e os 2 values. Alguem pode ajudar?

Comment: Tá usando Repository?  2 values e 2 keys vindas do input? só se for com `array`. Assim `key[] =1&key[]=2`

Comment: Fiz com repository porque é o unico jeito que eu sei fazer, mas se tiver outro modo, sem usar o repository, eu posso/consigo usar.

Comment: Eu só uso o Laravel sem Repository. Respository é para algo bem específico, como por exemplo, a necessidade de mudar o seu Orm. Acho que o ORM do Laravel já é bastante potente.

Comment: Como ficaria o update usando o ORM ?

Comment: Esse método na verdade é do Controller, né? Porque tá passando `Request`. Na verdade, você precisa explicar como vai vir dois valores em Keys e Values. Isso vem do formulário?

Comment: O update normal do ORM é `Cliente::where(['id' => $id])->update(['nome' => 'Nome', ' endereco' => 'Rua blablala'])`.

Comment: O formulario esta construido assim: {!! Form::open(array('method'=>'put', 'url' => url())) !!}                                                                        @foreach()
 <div class="input-group" style="margin-top: 10px">
{!! Form::hidden('key', $key) !!}
 {!! Form::text('value', '')) !!}
<button> submit</button>
 @endforeach
{!! Form::close() !!}

Comment: @IvanMoreira você pode nos explicar melhor o seu problema? você quer atualizar várias linhas do seu banco de dados certo? então você está recebendo mais de um id ou eu entendi o problema errado? adicione mais detalhes e código por favor.

Comment: @RafaelBerro O problema ja foi solucionado, eu utilizei a reposta abaixo e fiz um foreach no controller para receber 1 ou mais chaves.

Comment: @IvanMoreira Ótimo, você deve seleciona-la como a solução para a sua questão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para você enviar um formulário com múltiplos valores, você precisa escrevê-lo da seguinte forma, para facilitar a alocação dos dados:

```
{!! Form::open(array('method'=>'put', 'url' => url())) !!}

 @foreach($array as $key)
        {!! Form::text("clientes[$key][nome]", '')) !!}
        {!! Form::text("clientes[$key][endereco]", '')) !!}
        {!! Form::submit('Submit') !!}
 @endforeach 
{!! Form::close() !
```

!}

No método responsável pelo salvamento dos dados, você poderia fazer assim:

```
foreach  ($request->clientes as $id_key => $dados) {
    Cliente::where(['id' => $id_key])->update($dados);
}
```

Note que a forma que eu declarei o `name` dos inputs acima, fará com que o PHP gere um `array` assim:

```
[
    1 => ['nome' => 'Padaria Xodó', 'endereco' => 'Av Um - 155'],
    2 => ['nome' => 'Locadora Zezé', 'endereco' => 'Av Dois - 300']
]
```

Assim, internamente, no `foreach`, você sempre atualizará os dados de acordo com o `id`, que é o índice do nosso array.

Comment: Desse jeito, ele diz que o ->update($dados) é uma string e ele tem que receber um array

Comment: Eu particularmente selecionaria todos os clientes em uma única querie. Por exemplo, Cliente::whereIn('id', array_keys($request->get('clientes')));.